# Dynamic comment box

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, frontend, signalr, .net-framework-version

I want to make a dynamic comment box in my project similar to Facebook where comments made are stored in database and displayed instantly on the page without reloading.

My project is based on .net framework and I am not using Angular or React. What's the best technique for me to achieve this?

I am thinking about using SignalR. I don't know whether that's the right solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR is a great solution but not the only one out there.

The tutorial below gives you basics, without the database aspect, to do real time chatting/commenting. In that example it uses a UL element, but you could use whatever elements you want to house your comments.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc

For the database side you will need to store the comments relative to user and post. Then you have to consider the other side for retrieving comments to push to the client which could be done by polling on the server side and push to client, timed request from the client to get any new comments, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have made an Ajax call to store the comment details into the database. I am looking for ways to retrieve that details without refreshing and in real time. If there are any better alternatives to SignalR that suits my requirements please do mention it:)

Comment: You can also make server calls from the client instead of Ajax calls. You can essentially replace all the Ajax methods with client/server calls with SignalR. The docs give some good examples and most of your questions can be searched out here for answers.